# FilterDescriptor in domain data source problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have below code in xaml.

```
    <dds:DomainDataSource x:Name="hastaDataSource" PageSize="10" LoadSize="40" QueryName="GetDzHST_HastaQuery" AutoLoad="True">
        <dds:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <src:dysDomainContext/>
        </dds:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <dds:DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors>
            <dds:FilterDescriptor
                PropertyPath="HST_SoyAd"
                Operator="Contains"
                IgnoredValue=""
                Value="{Binding ElementName=txtHastaSoyad, Path=Text}" >
            </dds:FilterDescriptor>
            <dds:FilterDescriptor  
                PropertyPath="HST_Ad"
                Operator="Contains"
                IgnoredValue=""
                Value="{Binding ElementName=txtHST, Path=Text}" >
            </dds:FilterDescriptor>

        </dds:DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors>
```

it gives error :
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004

---> System.InvalidOperationException: The FilterDescriptor with its PropertyPath equal to 'HST_Ad' cannot be evaluated. 
---> System.ArgumentException: Operator 'Contains' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Object' 
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type String does not expose a method called 'Contains'.

If I write one Filterdescriptor in FilterDescriptors node, I works fine but using multiple filter, it gives an error as above.

Please help. thanks..

Comment: Please don't add answers that aren't, uh, answers.  You can add a bounty to your question (the system will loan you 50 points, plus whatever you wish to place on it), which will help bring some attention to your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add a `FilterOperator` to your `DomainDataSource` when you have multiple filters. The `FilterOperator` value should be either `"And"` or `"Or"`.

So it should be either `FilterOperator="And"` or `FilterOperator="Or"`.